# Group Policy - Internet Explorer Proxy Exceptions for private network 10.0.0.0/8

Tags: internet-explorer, group-policy, windows-server-2016

could you help me out?

What's the correct notation in Internet Explorer Connection Settings for Proxy concerning Proxy Exceptions (bypassing enabled) for private network 10.0.0.0/8 ?

I tried 10.*.*.*, but after setting User GPO, Internet Explorer still redirects to proxy page when typing a non-existing example address like http://10.10.0.50 or https://10.10.0.50.

We all know that there's no possibility in GPO for subnet mask or CIDR for bypass intranet sites connecting via IP. Or should I implement just the network ID like 10.0.0.0 without a Mask, so it is assumed for all class A network?

I could not find an official document from Microsoft for such case, only bypassing domainnames with wildcard *.

I'm sure I need a PAC for class B and class C network addresses for bypassing them, but let's fix the 10.0.0.0/8 - class A at least with classic GPO.

Answer (score 0):

the mask format is odd in IE, please try "10.*"